# Why can't we use integral of $x$, $y$ and $z$ in calculating moment of inertia

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, definition, moment-of-inertia

I've got no problems with calculating the moment of inertia/tensor of inertia of a cube using an integral over the lamina of a cube. However, I must be missing something obvious or making some sort of silly mistake but doing an integral over all three dimensions like

$$ \int_V \rho r^2 dV = \int_V \rho (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dxdydz,$$

does not give the correct answer. Is there something I am missing in why this is not actually valid?

Comment: The "$r$" in $r^2dm$ is the distance from the axis, not the origin. See e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705908).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Definition) is defined for a specific rotation *axis*.
The radius $r$ is the distance from this *axis*, not from the
origin *point*.
For example, for the moment of inertia around
the $z$-axis the radius is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but not
$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.